# How can I use fieldsets with a partial template in admin.py?

Tags: python, django, templates, modeladmin

In admin.py I'm using fieldsets to display my fields in the change view. I want to keep using fieldsets, but also add a partial html template that renders an editable table on the same view.

I've looked through the django docs and I haven't been able to find a way to include both fieldsets and add a template 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects